# Android thread access to DB class

Tags: android, multithreading

basic question - I'm still learning Android - trying to create a seperate thread to do a DB query and having a problem. I've put my DB routines in their own class but can't seem to access it from the thread:

```
public class TripsScreenActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public class dbThread extends AsyncTask<Cursor, Integer, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Cursor... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Link to WYWHApplication module
        WYWHApplication wywh = (WYWHApplication) this.getApplication();

        try {
            Cursor tripList = wywh.getBasicList();
```

...but Eclipse is giving me the following error:

```
The method getApplication() is undefined for the type TripsScreenActivity.dbThread
```

Sorry, probably an obvious answer...any help gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the `AsyncTask` when used inside `doInBackground()`.You want to refer to your activity, so use `TripsScreenActivity.this.getApplication()`¹ instead of `this.getApplication()`.

¹ *that's called a "qualified this"*